# Express route not working but deliberate error in code shows it is being called correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I have a very strange problem with an Express route whereby a perfectly valid `console.log` does not display and no other lines of code after it execute when the route is hit.

For example:

```
app.get('/api/v1/users', (req, res) => {
   console.log('Users route has been reached....') // does not display in console
   ...
  // No other code executes
}
```

However, to test if the route is actually being hit I purposely created an error in the console.log like so:

`console.log('Route has been reached....) // missing end quote`

And when I check the logs, I can see the following error.

`0|index    | /home/ubuntu/apps/api/server/index.js:119 0|index    |   console.log('Route has been reached........) 0|index    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 0|index    |  0|index    | SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

This must mean that the route is being hit correctly but for some reason doesn't execute its request properly. My logic is that if the line with the bad `console.log` is reached then I cannot see why the correct one doesn't even log out at all.

I am a bit stumped as to what is going on so any ideas or assistance on what the problem could be is very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: "This must mean that the route is being hit correctly but for some reason doesn't execute its request properly." — No, it means the module fails to compile.

Comment: How much you can rely on deliberately throwing syntax error like missing end quote, this kind of error, might even get caught when you run the server (compile time). Doesn't definitely proofs that route is being hit. There might be an issue, that this route is never getting reached.

Comment: I believe the reason you see that error message occurring is not because the route is being hit, but rather when your code is being compiled for execution the JavaScript engine recognizes the missing quote resulting in a syntax error. Do you have any other routes defined above this particular route that could be getting matched instead which results in this route not being hit?

Comment: Yes, I see now, the console error is occurring probably a compile error. The problem must be deeper in the API . I have multiple other routes that follow the same pattern and work fine, so I'll need to have a closer look at it to figure it out. Thanks for pointing out my obvious illogical thinking!